# Ubuntu 10.04.4 - time length and support

Tags: 10.04, disk

The end of life of official support for Ubuntu lucid 10.04.4 is  2013. Personally, I'll stick to 10.04 and I won't leave it at all.

Have something magic that even Unity can't replace it. Can canonical provide (with payment), a disk that will contain all data for lucid. all universe . etc... ? and where I can buy one?

Comment: You must set one of the answer that you received as `accepted answer` *(the button below the arrows, on the left side of the answer)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu maintains a archive of releases from 6.06 to current "old-releases", those that have reached their (EOL) end of life. These can be found [HERE](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/). These old releases WILL NOT receive updates as their repositories are removed but .ISO's remain.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess Ubuntu Advantage would be a good place to start if you are willing to pay for services. What you're really asking for is a snapshot of all the repos, which is no different than mirroring, which you can do yourself for free.

It's not as if the images are destroyed, it's just security updates cease after a while, at which point you would have to scramble and perhaps confine it to a VM with only the bare necessities open to the world, even then, that's a massive headache.

Everyone's apps grow roots, you'd be better off to begin the effort now to port whatever it is you're dependent on forward, perhaps even package it. Good luck.